# Extracting values during monte carlo simulation with for() function

Tags: r, montecarlo

I run a monte carlo simulation for optimization and want to know how a value maximizes during my sampling process.
Small simplified example of my process:

```
df<-expand.grid(data.frame(A=seq(0,1,length.out=20), B=seq(0,2,length.out=20), C=seq(0,3,length.out=20)))%>%
  distinct()

sampling_function<- function(x){
  repeat {
    
    Point<-x[sample(nrow(x),size=1),1:3]%>%
      mutate(Score=A*B*C)
    
    if(Point$Score >= 1) break
  }
  return(Point)
}

m.c <- NULL
n=1000
for (k in 1:n)
{
  P<-sampling_function(df)
  
  m.c = rbind(m.c, data.frame(P))
}
```

Goal is to monitor the Score and plot it over n to figure out how much sampling is needed to maximize the score.
Is there an elegant way to put it into the function?

I thought of something like:

```
for (k in 1:n)
{
  P<-sampling_function(df)
  
  m.c <- rbind(m.c, data.frame(P))%>%
    mutate(Score_max=case_when(Score>=lag(Score,1L)~Score,
                               Score<=lag(Score,1L)~lag(Score,1L)))
}
```

Problem here is the number of columns which is not the same so rbind has a problem. I tried a lot but I guess the problem is in the rbind() approach.

Any ideas? Maybe its a typical thing of overthinking...

**EDIT**
to make things clearer: my original df is based on expand.grid() but with several constraints and more variables. I do a mc simulation with several functions like the mentioned "sampling_function" to get various "selections of spaces" within my df. The mentioned Score here is just a placeholder for a more complex calculation which gives a value which I wanna maximize (or optimize). I don´t wanna use a optimizer for this so I tried it with basic R code. As an Output I would like to have a data.frame that has the number of sampling steps and the calculated max(Score) so i can plot them like an typical output from an optimizer.

```
Sampling_number Score_max
1            1000       4.0
2            1001       4.3
3            1002       4.4
4            1003       4.9
5            1004       5.4
```

Hopefully now it more clear.

As an alternative solution: is there a function to summarize all rows above, but not below? Could be implemented in the m.c outside of the function.Would cost a lot of CPU Power but maybe it is the better way...

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. `Score` is just the product of columns A, B, C. Given your data, the maximum Score would be 6 (i.e. the product of the last row). What do you want to maximize? How often you need to sample until you get the maximum score of 6?

Comment: Exactly right! It is just an simple example to show my problem.

Comment: Same interrogations for my part, I do not understand your objective, could you elaborate on your desired output ? This is clear that m.c and P have different number of columns and I don't understand your rationale behind the code

Comment: hm, so you want to know how likely you'll get one specific row, given a certain sample size n? This might be easier to handle as a theoretical probability prob rather than as a simulation...

Comment: Edited it - hope now it is more clear.